# What can I further do to test these Expresso Store hooks that appear to be not happening?

Tags: expresso-store, hook

EE 2.7.2
Store 2.0.3

It doesn't look like the hook (store_order_recalculate_end) is happening as advertised. Works fine when adding the first item to the cart. But upon cart update or adding more items, not happening.

Here is a dead simple test in my extension. (via template logging)

```
...
'hook' => 'store_order_recalculate_end',
'method' => 'barfoo',
...

public function barfoo(){

    $this->EE->load->library('Template', null, 'TMPL');
    $this->EE->TMPL->log_item("Hello World");

    }
```

What else can I be doing? Where should I be looking? This method definitely does not happen after the first item is added to the cart.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Furthermore, none of these hooks

https://exp-resso.com/docs/extension_hooks.html#order_update_hooks

are happening on cart updates.

Comment: It only runs on a POST request which immediately redirects, so you wouldn't see anything in the template logs. What does `exit("hello")` in your hook do?

Comment: Cool. Just wrote up a quick answer to help anyone else stuck on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the hooks were running, but it was more a case of the logged messages not appearing.

Store uses the Post-Redirect-Get pattern, which means that the cart is updated (and hooks run) during an HTTP POST request. When the cart has finished updating (unless there were any errors), it redirects the customer's browser back to the checkout page using a GET request (this prevents them from accidentally resubmitting the form when hitting refresh etc).

Therefore in your case the messages logged in the template library were lost when the customer's browser was redirected, hence why they weren't displayed.

Comment: Quick followup, if I may. Is it true that none of these hooks run when we use the "Empty Cart" button?

Comment: Correct, the cart doesn't get recalculated when you empty it (Store just unsets the user's cookie). We could certainly add an extra hook to run when the cart is emptied if you need it though.

Comment: Well, if you get to it that would be cool. But I can certainly get around it for the time being. I see you've already added a couple more in 2.0.4